# Is there a way to iterate through a javascript object's prototype variables and functions?

Tags: javascript-objects, javascript

**This question is no longer applicable to what I'm trying to do because I have to declare the name of the pmp objects with a name.**

I want to be able to associate an object with each prototype function for my class without doing it manually for each prototype.
I've tried seeing what's inside prototype with the following methods, but to no avail

```
myclass.prototype.length == undefined;
myclass.prototype.toString() == [object Object];
myclass.prototype == [object Object];
```

This is my code. In the following lines:

```
this.appear = _pmp(k8rModal.prototype._appear);
this.centerSlate = _pmp(k8rModal.prototype._centerSlate);
this.adjustToScreenResize = _pmp(k8rModal.prototype._adjustToScreenResize);
```

I run a function called '_pmp' that creates a PreMainPost object that appear,centerSlate & adjustToScreenResize will refer to. These objects have a .run() function that will first run the pre() functions then the main() function which is being defined by the constructor parameter and then finally the post() functions.

This is all the context:
k8r-modal.js

```
function k8rModal(DOMnamespace){
var _ = this._ = DOMnamespace+"_"; // for DOM namespacing

this.tightWrap=1;
this.visible = 0;

$('body').prepend('<div id="'+_+'stage"></div>');
this.stage = stage = $('#'+_+'stage');
stage.css({
    'display':'none',
    'width':'100%',
    'height':'100%',
    'position': 'fixed',
    'left':'0px',
    'top':'0px',
    'opacity': '.6',
    'background-color':'#333'
});

$('body').append('<div id="'+_+'slate"></div>');
this.slate = slate = $('#'+_+'slate');
slate.css({
    'display':'none',
    'width':'640px',
    'height':'480px',
    'position': 'fixed',
    'left':'0px',
    'top':'0px',
    'background-color':'#eee'
});

var k8rModalInstance = this;
$('.'+_+'caller').on('click',function(){
    k8rModalInstance.appear.run();
});

this.appear = _pmp(k8rModal.prototype._appear);
this.centerSlate = _pmp(k8rModal.prototype._centerSlate);
this.adjustToScreenResize = _pmp(k8rModal.prototype._adjustToScreenResize);

this.centerSlate.run();
this.word="asdf";
$(window).resize(function(){
    alert(k8rModalInstance.word)
  k8rModalInstance.adjustToScreenResize.run();
});
}

k8rModal.prototype._appear = function(){
this.that.visible = 1;
this.that.slate.show();
this.that.stage.show();
}

k8rModal.prototype._centerSlate = function(){
var wWidth, wHeight, slate = $(this.that.slate) ;

wWidth = $(window).width();
wHeight = $(window).height();

slate.css({
    top: (wHeight/2 - ( slate.height()/2))+"px",
    left: ( wWidth/2 - ( slate.width()/2 ) )+"px"
});
}

k8rModal.prototype._adjustToScreenResize = function(){
this.that.centerSlate.run();

}
```

(pre-main-post.js) pmp.js:

```
function _pmp(func){
return new pmp(this,func);
}

function pmp(that,func){
var func;
this.pre = new funcList();
this.post = new funcList();
this.main = func;
this.that = that;
}

pmp.prototype.run = function(arg){
this.pre.run(arg);
this.post.run(arg,this.main());
}

pmp.prototype.trim = function(){
this.pre = new funcList();
this.post = new funcList();
}
```

(an object that contains a list of functions)funcList.js:

```
function funcList(){
this.unique; // if a function can be 
this.list=[];
}

funcList.prototype.add = function(func){
if (this.unique){
    var passing = 1;
    for(var i; i<this.list.length; i+=1){
        if (list[i].toString == func.toString){
            passing = 0;
        }
    }
    if (passing){
        this.list.push(func);   
    }
}else{
    this.list.push(func);
}
}

funcList.prototype.remove = function(func){
for(var i; i<this.list.length; i+=1){
    if (list[i].toString == func.toString){
        this.list.splice(i,1);
    }
}
}

funcList.prototype.clear = function(){
this.list = [];
}

funcList.prototype.run = function(arg){
for(var i; i<this.list.length; i+=1){
    (this.list[i])(arg);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you able to clarify what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: show the code "you doing it manually for each prototype".

Comment: Does this help?: http://jsfiddle.net/gQUn3/1/

Comment: I suppose the question is no longer relevant because I still have to declare the name of the variables that I assign the functions to (which are really objects that contains lists of functions).

Answer (score 1):

Only the prototypes for natives and functions are accessible to you. If myClass is a function, you can iterate over its prototype by using

```
for(var prop in myClass.prototype){
    console.log(myClass.prototype[prop]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*only the prototypes for natives and functions are accessible*"? Which prototype objects are "not accessible"?

Comment: @Bergi The internal [[Prototype]] property of an object declared like this: `var x = {};` is not accessible except through the use of Object.getPrototypeOf(x). Perhaps I should have said *directly* accessible?

Comment: OK, "not accessible as a direct property" - unless you count non-standard `__proto__` :-)